# angular2: the missing "detail view" service tutorial

Tags: angular, angular2-services

Virtually all tutorials show how to create a service that retrieves data like

```json
[
  {"id":1, "name":"cat"}, 
  {"id":2, "name":"dog"}, 
  {"id":3, "name":"cow"}, 
  ...
]
```

and  show how a component can consume such a service using `*ngFor`.

But how about a scenario where I want to get a lot more data based on a selection of one of these. For example I select dog from the 'list service' above using `*ngFor` selection to call a 'detail service' like

```json
[
  {
    "id":2, 
    "name":"dog", 
    "species": "canine", 
    "weight": "2-100kg",
    "height": "10-100cm", 
    "smell": "good", 
    "character" : "great", 
    ... 
  }
]
```

which I want to consume on a detail component.

How do I "consume" such a service? `*ngFor` for one individual entry does not feel right, especially as I might want to show the different parts in completely different areas of the template and not in a `<li>` list.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a select action that feeds your structure.

```
<select [ngModel]="selectedOption" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" name="sel">
    <option [value]="i" *ngFor="let i of options">{{i}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: That is exactly **what I want to avoid**, as it would require me to load all the data from the start whether it is required or not. Lets think of a scenario where the payload for each record is 20kb  with 100 records the would mean I would have to load 2MB every time even if the user just wants one single record. Thus I want to just use a minimal data set to make the selection and then only load the relevant record from an independent service. But **no** tutorial shows you how to do that - I have looked at loads of them and I am stuck.